# How can I play/stop a song from playing using NSSound?

Tags: objective-c, nssound

I am using `NSSound` to play a song from my FTP server.

**My problem:**

The 1st song won't stop, overlapping in this way the 2nd second song.

Here I paste the full code. This is the behavior when I click on a song in a `NSTableView`

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{

   NSInteger row = [[notification object] selectedRow];
   NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ftp://user:pass@IP/Public/Music/%@",[TableContents objectAtIndex:row]];

   NSSound *song = [[NSSound alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL] byReference:NO];

   NSLog(@"is playing before %hhd", song.isPlaying);

      if(song.isPlaying){
        [song stop];
        NSLog(@"is playing IF if %hhd", song.isPlaying);

      }else{
        [song play];
        NSLog(@"is playing ELSE %hhd", song.isPlaying);
      }

}
```

**Output:**

When I click on the 1st song:

```
2018-10-06 23:51:08.488690+0200 AIOMediaCenter[4294:492923] is playing before 0
2018-10-06 23:51:08.489099+0200 AIOMediaCenter[4294:492923] is playing ELSE 1
```

When I click on the 2nd song:

```
2018-10-06 23:51:12.022284+0200 AIOMediaCenter[4294:492923] is playing before 0
2018-10-06 23:51:12.022375+0200 AIOMediaCenter[4294:492923] is playing ELSE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click it, you're creating a new `song` object. You need to store a pointer to the `song` object somewhere when you create a new one, and then check if 1) the object exists, 2) `isPlaying` is `TRUE` in order to stop it. That's going to take more planning out on your part. It is outside the scope of the question.

(You're also never releasing `song` after allocating it, which will leak memory.)